# Android code to add email-id along with name,phone number in phone's contact

Tags: android

Actually I am able to add name and phone number in phone's contact programatically using Android code. And now I want to add email Address along with name and number.
Can somebody post the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
 values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
 values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "1-800-GOOG-411");
 values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
 values.put(Phone.LABEL, "free directory assistance");
 values.put(Email.DATA, "somebody@android.com")
 Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Use the above code. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html)
don't forget to add permission in manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />,
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />`